# Regex to find word 1 or word 2 but not word 3

Tags: command-line, bash, ruby, regex

I have the following message:

`Apr 12 12:48:02 poe true: sudo:   nagios : command not allowed ; TTY=unknown ; PWD=/var/log/nagios`;

How do I make a regex that looks for the word Sudo or Command but not to look for the word true? Reason being I have other messages that have just the words sudo and command and i'm not interested in viewing the messages with the combination of those 2 words with that 3rd word. I have so far tried:

1.(?=.*word1)(?=.*word2)
2. word1.*word2

Both of them failed to exlcude the word that I don't want. Basically I want the resultant set to not consist of those messages that would have word3 along with word1 and word2 but want the resultant set to have either word1 or word2.

Thanks!

(*Added from comment*)

```
<30>Jun 11 12:42:02 true:/var/ossec/logs/alerts/alerts.log Apr 12 12:48:01 duffy sudo: nagios : command not allowed ; TTY=unknown ; PWD=/var/log/nagios; 
<85>Apr 11 12:00:46 verne sudo: ndakjs2 : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/Defactor/2/rules/claimsfactor ; USER=NONE; COMMAND
```

If you take both that above messages, I want the regex to match the second message since it has the word `sudo` in it, but not match the first message as it has the word `true` in it. I'm only interested in the resultant set without the word `TRUE`. Although that 1st message has `Sudo`, I don't want that message.

Comment: Unless you're trying to match words *in order*, wouldn't it be simpler to test each pattern separately and combine them logically? e.g. `(/command/ || /sudo/) && !/true/`

Comment: @steeldriver: Thanks for that, test word always comes before sudo or command. Does that help simplify it?

Comment: I don't know much about regex's, but for some reason regex101 is not able to take the above posted syntax as is, I had to remove all the /'s and double ||. Could you make it compatible with regex101 syntax as my application uses that kinda syntax?

Comment: It's multiple expressions. I don't know how that would be implemented in your (`ruby`?) application. Sorry.

Comment: If you want to exclude `sudo` when it's *immediately* preceded by `true: ` ("true-colon-space") then in PCRE you could do `(?<!true: )sudo.*command`

Comment: That would have been perfect it there were no other strings inbetween true and sudo, but unfortunately in most of other messages, I have other strings in the middle, so would (?<!true:*)sudo.*command would work?

I'm thinking excludeword1 AND match word2 | word3, I don't know what would be the best way to put it together.

Comment: It depends - many regex engines don't support variable-length lookbehinds. Really you should be **specific** about the engine you're using and the **exact** requirement (i.e. specific examples of what you want to include and exclude).

Comment: I apologize for not being more specific than what I am, but I am fairly new to Regex. I can tell you this, if you copy paste my original message into Regex101.com website and come up with a pattern that can perform the operation of Match Word1 or Word2 but when you match Word3 don't put it in the resultant output set, that will work with my application. I am not aware of what underlying engine this application uses but I have seen it work with exact syntax from Regex101.com

Comment: <30>Jun 11 12:42:02 true:/var/ossec/logs/alerts/alerts.log Apr 12 12:48:01 duffy sudo:   nagios : command not allowed ; TTY=unknown ; PWD=/var/log/nagios;

<85>Apr 11 12:00:46 verne sudo:  ndakjs2 : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/Defactor/2/rules/claimsfactor ; USER=NONE; COMMAND

If you take both that above messages, I want the regex to match the second message since it has the word sudo in it, but not match the first message as it has the word True in it. I'm only interested in the resultant set without the word TRUE. Although that 1st message has Sudo, I don't want that message.

Comment: Using (sudo|command) it matches both messages, adding to that, I want to avoid it matching the first message and that's all I need as an adjustment. If you use those messages and that string above in regex101 to experiment and provide a better one I would greatly appreciate it! (BTW, in that above comment where it has <85> is the start of a new message).

Comment: Does your log messages alway contain either of these three words?

Comment: It does always contain the word True or Sudo. If not it contains Sudo or Command, or it contains True or Command, but what i'm interested in is just the messages that have sudo / command and not True.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking for this

```
^(?!.*true).*$
```

The thing `(?!...)` is a negative look-ahead operator which checks if any word exists. Check it here http://rubular.com/r/aYzwcfekrI

Credit goes to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17797426/1039893).

You can also just use a regular program to check if it contains the word `true`.

Assuming `lines` is an array of log messages, it would be something like this

```
lines.each do |line|
  puts line unless line.include?("true")
end
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Anwar, but that above syntax seem to skip everything, both messages that have the word sudo or command and it also skips the message that has the word True. It's doing what's is supposed to, but it doesn't match what I want.

Comment: Are all your messages contain either of these words?

Comment: @Tk_93 please add at least one log messages of each variant

Comment: In the original description above I added 2 logs that show this.

Comment: @Anwar https://regex101.com/r/iBqEWL/1/